# How to use header functions in source file in C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, declaration

I'm new to C++ programming language and it is different from Java. I tried to use functions from a header I made but when I use a function from the header , Eclipse C++ IDE says that member declaration is not found except for the constructor while it is found in the header as public.

Car.h file (header) :

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Car {
private :
    string name;
    string model;
    int year;
    int width;
    int height;
    int depth;
public :
     Car ();
     Car (string n, string m, int y, int w, int h, int d);
     void setName(string n);
     void setModel (string m);
     void setYear (int y);
     void setSize (int w, int h, int d);
     string getName ();
     string getModel();
     int getYear();
     int getWidth();
     int getHeight();
     int getDepth();

};
```

Car.cpp file (source)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

Car::Car(string n, string m, int y, int w, int h, int d) { //works properly
  name = n;
  model = m;
  year = y;
  width = w;
  height = h;
  depth = d;
}

Car::getName() { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return name;
}

Car::getModel() { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return model;
}

Car::getYear() { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return year;
}

Car::getWidth() { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return width;
}

Car::getHeight () { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return height;
}
```

What I have did wrong ?

Comment: This may violate the style rules under which you are programming, but the methods can be completely defined inside the class definition. For obvious and simple functions like `int getYear() {return year}`, putting the implementation in the class definition header can save you coding time and result in cleaner code.

Comment: And even create faster code through inlining

Answer (score 3):

All of your functions are missing the return type, for example

```
string Car::getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Car works is because it is a Constructor and does not need a type declaration.

All the rest of your functions do.

```
int Car::getYear() { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return year;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

Car::Car(string n, string m, int y, int w, int h, int d) { //works properly
  name = n;
  model = m;
  year = y;
  width = w;
  height = h;
  depth = d;
}

string Car::getName() { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return name;
}

string Car::getModel() { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return model;
}

int Car::getYear() { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return year;
}

int Car::getWidth() { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return width;
}

int Car::getHeight () { // IDE says member declaration not found
    return height;
}
```